# Converting a data.frame into a table

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame and I want to change into a table. It has three columns: Number, Study, Classes and Year. I've slitting it into those different Classes   (nursery, grammar school, college), producing 9 different dataframes each bellowing to a different class. In the end I've excluded the Class column maintaining just the Number, Study and Year. After that I've converting each of those dataframes, classified by classes, into a table, using:

```
GT <- xtabs(G$Number ~ G$Study + G$Year, G)
```

However, this equation continues bring the Class former information, the one I've cut down. I've no clue about what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O. To get better help, I encourage you to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Also, provide more details about what you want to achieve, the code you have used so far and the error messages that you get, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you dropped coloumn "Class"?
Try this:

```
Grammar <- subset(data, data$class=="Grammar", select=c("Number", "Study", "Year")
GT <- xtabs(Number ~ Study + Year, Grammar)
```